# LiquiBase - Passing Parameter From CommandLine Or Properties to Changeset XML

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to pass a parameter from my update command as well as the liquibase properties file to my changeset. For some reason, it does not recognise the placeholder as a parameter but parses it as a value.

This is how I invoke the changeLog (which runs successfully):

```
@echo off
call Liquibase --changeLogFile=myChangeLogFile.xml update -Dparamname=value
```

myChangeLogFile.xml:

```
<changeSet author="tobi" id="preMigration" runAlways="true">
    <executeCommand executable="C:\myBatFile.bat">
        <arg value="${liquibase.properties.Dparamname}"/>
        <arg value="${liquibase.properties.url}"/>
    </executeCommand>  
</changeSet>
```

The script does not recognise ${liquibase.properties.Dparamname} or ${liquibase.properties.url} as placeholders.

My Liquibase.properties file has the

```
url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz:1521:ORCL
```

parameter set.

Any idea how I can access the properties or the command line parameters?

Thank you

I would appreciate your feedback.

Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using this in your changelog:

```
<changeSet author="tobi" id="preMigration" runAlways="true">
    <executeCommand executable="C:\myBatFile.bat">
        <arg value="${liquibase.properties.Dparamname}"/>
        <arg value="${liquibase.properties.url}"/>
    </executeCommand>  
</changeSet>
```

it should look more like this:

```
<changeSet author="tobi" id="preMigration" runAlways="true">
    <executeCommand executable="C:\myBatFile.bat">
        <arg value="${paramname}"/>
        <arg value="${url}"/>
    </executeCommand>  
</changeSet>
```

The `-D` on the command line is the standard java mechanism for setting system properties, but when accessing them you just use the property name. I am fairly certain that you don't need to use the `liquibase.properties` prefix either.

Comment: Thank you

The ${paramname} worked fine. Unfortunately, I was not able to reference parameters of the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I have a requirement like calling a .bat file with parameters from liquibase upgrade scripts.
Also also this should run only one time like change set.

Thanks,
Jagadeesh