# Different paramaters in one liquibase .properties file possible?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, liquibase

Hey all I am wondering if its possible to place different .properties inside just one .properties file so that I do not have to make a seprate .praperties file for each of my database?

[This site](https://mohitgoyal.co/2019/03/20/selectively-apply-changes-to-database-environments-using-liquibase/) here is doing what I would like to do but it doesnt explain how to go about sending those contexts to the .properties file. And it also seems to be using seprate .properties files. As in, it doesnt show me how it should look inside the .properties file. Another good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368969/liquibase-passing-parameter-from-commandline-or-properties-to-changeset-xml) is here but again, it doesnt do it in the .properties file.

Let's say I have the following inside my .properties file:

```
#liquibase.properties file content
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxx.str3.xxxxx.xxxxx:1511/xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx
username: SEPRATE_1PEGA_BASEDA
password: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
referenceUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxx.str2.xxxxx.xxxxx:1511/xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx
referenceUsername: SEPRATE_1PEGA_BASEDB
referencePassword: YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
changeLogFile: diff_change.txt
diffTypes: tables, views, columns, indexes, foreignkeys, primarykeys, uniqueconstraints
```

And I am wanting to send a paramater to replace the "str2" and "SEPRATE_1PEGA_BASEDB" varibles currently hard-coded inside the .properties file. So I write the .properties file like so:

```
#liquibase.properties file content
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxx.str3.xxxxx.xxxxx:1511/xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx
username: SEPRATE_1PEGA_BASEDA
password: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
referenceUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxx.${liquibase.properties.str}.xxxxx.xxxxx:1511/xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx
referenceUsername: ${liquibase.properties.un}
referencePassword: YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
changeLogFile: diff_change.txt
diffTypes: tables, views, columns, indexes, foreignkeys, primarykeys, uniqueconstraints
```

So would the CLI for this look like:

`liquibase --str=str5 --un=BobBarker diff`

My liquibase version is `Liquibase-3.6.2`.

Comment: Anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your need properly, you would like to replace placeholders inside your property files.

There are 2 things you should think of:

- changelog parameter substitutions - I didn't tested that but if you define property `parameter.testproperty=originalvalue` and then you put on commandline `-Dtestproperty=overridenvalue` it could probably replace your value and you will be able to use it in changelogs
- liquibase configuration parameters substitution - Liquibase is not doing this, because it's reading properties [just like they are in file](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/85f71ffbd23f0e4d2faa39bea6bc0244e389cd34/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/commandline/Main.java#L1038) (method `parsePropertiesFile` last if/else) and it's trying to fill fields in java with that values. So for this you will need to replace placeholders before calling liquibase command or use different property file.

Comment: in the .properties file are you talking about something like this?
**changeLogFile: parameter.testproperty=diff_change2.txt** and then in the CLI i would do 
**liquibase -Dtestproperty=diff_change3.txt diff**. Would doing that change **diff_change2.txt** to **diff_change3.txt**?

Comment: Doing this it tells me **Unexpected value '-Dproperty.testproperty=something.txt' (options must start with a '--')**

Comment: maybe you have wrong order of properties... try `java -Dproperty=something.txt <here liquibase commands>`

Comment: Yeah still the same thing :(